# Jqgrid inline edit displays nbsp; instead of spaces for one column

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

jqgrid column contains phone number.

For one row, if inline edit has started, `&nbsp;` characters appear instead of spaces:

Before:

[image: before]

After edit has started:

[image: afteredit]

After saving nbsp; is also saved in phone number.
How to fix or diagnose this ?

Those characters appear also if form edit is used.
Other rows where phone number also contains spaces appear properly. Other columns in this row also appear properly.

This column colmodel:

```
{"label":"Telefon","name":"Telefon","index":"Telefon","editoptions":{"maxlength":25,"size":25,"dataEvents":[{"type":"change","fn":function(e) {dataChanged(e.target)}
},{"type":"focus","fn":function(e) {if(typeof e.target.ischanged=='undefined') {e.target.ischanged=false}}
}],"readonly":null,"class":null,"disabled":null},"editable":true,"width":66,"classes":null,"hidden":false,"searchoptions":{"sopt":["cn","eq","ne","lt","le","gt","ge","bw","ew","nc"]},"stype":"text"},
```

jqgrid is populated from json data in server:

```
{"total":1,"page":1,"rows":[{"id":"7","cell":[null,"","7","XXXanval Mll OÜ","Tarnija","","","","","","","","","","3 725 141 100","","","Ursel","","","","","","","","","","02","",""]}]}
```

Other rows which are populated properly contain similar data, maybe some more columsn are filled.

jqgrid settings:

```
   $.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
        mtype: 'POST',

        toppager: true,
        viewrecords: false,
        recordpos: 'center',
        pagerpos: 'right',
        rowList: [50, 500, 1000],
        rowNum: 50,
        rownumbers: true,
        onSelectRow: grid_onSelectRow,
        onSelectAll: grid_onSelectAll,
        multiselect: true,
        ajaxRowOptions: { async: true },
        scrollrows: true,
        prmNames: {  
            id: "_rowid", page: "_page", rows: "_rows", oper: "_oper", sort: "_sidx", order: "_sord",
            nd: "_nd"
        },
        loadui: 'block',
        cmTemplate: { fixed: true },
        autoencode: true,
        gridview: true,
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem exists in *your input data*. You posed incorrect data. The real data **already contains** [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). The JSON data returned by your server are **not** `"3 725 141 100"` (with spaces inside, the space have the code 32 or 0x20), but `"3 725 141 100"` (with non-breaking spaces inside, which have the code 160 or 0xA0).

UTF-8 encoded data in the HTTP traffic looks like

[image]

The decoded data look like

[image]

The above picture displays the fragment of your original JSON data displayed in the HEX format. I marked with green color the standard space and with red color the space used in the data returned from your server. To solve the problem you should normalize your data either in the database or in your server code or on the client side in your JavaScript code. In any way you should replace all unneeded non-breaking spaces to the standard space.

Comment: Non-breaking space is correct data. However it is converted to &nbsp; characters on save. In jqgrid starting editing and saving without any changes causes data corruption. How to fix this so that jqgrid shows and saves non-breaking space properly on edit ?

Comment: @Andrus: I don't think that the usage of Non-breaking space in the input data is the standard case. If you need to edit such data with saving the original `&nbsp;` (`&#160;`) then you should use some HTML editor like tinyMCE instead of the standard text input. What I suggest you to do is to text your input for `&#160;` characters and to replace such symbols to the space.

Comment: Phone numbers are copied using copy and paste from documents. Non breaking space means that additional spacing or wrapping is not allowed. It is useful if number is copied back to document from jqgrid. This is standard usage. In inline editing input field is one line heigth and its width is column width. tinyMCE and others require much more space for editing. How to use them so that editing does not take more space than input type=text element?

Comment: @Andrus: I'm not sure that exact format of input data you could have and in what format you need to save it. You can use simple edit field, but to make an addition replacing of `&#160;` before starting of inline editing and replace spaces back to `&#160;`. I can imagine many alternative implementations, but all there seems me be very close to the *specific* format of your data. I think that the most problem was to find *the reason* of such strange behavior. The workaround seems to me not so complex.

Comment: This looks like a jQGrid bug to me. The non-breaking spaces really do come about from copy and pasting from pdfs and documents. It's incorrect for jQGrid to just literally insert an HTML entity (&nbsp;) into a pure text area. Printing the original non-breaking space character would have been more correct. Unfortunately, only workaround that I could find for this is to pre-clean the text strings of non-breaking spaces.